# iOS :: 'TestFairy.h' file not found

Tags: ios, testfairy

I am trying to integrate **TestFairy SDK** into the **iOS** project for testing. I am following [steps](http://docs.testfairy.com/iOS_SDK/Integrating_iOS_SDK.html).

But in the second step I am not understanding where to drag and drop the SDK.
I added test fairy sdks by right click on project in the **Navigator--> Add files to --> select directory** and check add to target.

If I import `TestFairy.h` as said in step 3, then it says:

> TestFairy.h file not found.

If anyone have used TestFairy, then please help me to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I  followed the instructions and I reproduced the error. My workaround was to drag the 3 files (withou the folder) and check "Copy items if needed" checkbox. Build was successfull. You can create a "Group" and put the three files in the virtual folder after you build.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included the TestFairy SDK files within a folder make sure you have foldername in you #import statement like

## #import "foldername/TestFairy.h"

Comment: can you share a screenshot of you project?

Answer (score 0):

When you drag files into your project, you can select "Copy files if needed". By default, this checkbox is on. Otherwise, it won't copy the files into your project, and the header file won't be in your include path. I will get the docs updated so this won't happen to others.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps from this link :
https://app.testfairy.com/sdk/ios/

Drag and drop all files from TestFairy SDK to your iOS Project with following settings:

1) Tick "Copy items if needed" 
2) Added folder: "Create Groups"
3) Now build the project.

[Image shows exact steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y17JY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just 3 things to check and it will work:

1. Drag that unzipped folder of TestFairy SDK into your project tree.
2. Check copy Items if needed.
3. Dont forget to import it in your bridging header file if you are using swift as - #import "TestFairy.h"